# Displaying arrows on pipes from upstream to downstream using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, direction, flow

I am trying to display arrows on pipes of a sewer network so their direction is from upstream to downstream edges of the pipes.

I have managed to display those arrows on a polyline layer (which is the pipes) from the properties menu, but their direction seems to always be from Northeast to Southwest, regardless of the upstream and downstream edges.

How do i connect the arrow direction to those edges?

For example in the picture, the pipe between Nodes D11122 and D115 should have the arrow directed the opposite way.

Each pipe has an upstream and a downstream edge. Each edge is connected with a node and their properties are shown in the attribute table.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If your vectors are not necessarily in the right direction and if you have a point shapefile with elevations and correct topology, I would suggest the following:

- Create a 'WKT' field in your point data with the WKT geometry of your
  point, using the field calculator:  `geom_to_wkt( $geometry)` ;
- For your pipe layer, choose expression-based rotation for your
  arrow marker:

[image: Expression-based rotation]

- And use an expression such as this one:

  ```
    CASE
    WHEN attribute(get_feature( 'Point_layer_name', 'WKT', geom_to_wkt(start_point( $geometry)) ),'Elevation_field') - attribute(get_feature( 'Point_layer_name', 'WKT', geom_to_wkt(end_point( $geometry)) ),'Elevation_field') < 0 THEN '270'
    ELSE '90'
    END
  ```

Answer (score 3):

There's a QGIS plugin [Switch the Direction of a Polyline](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lineswitch/) that does exactly what it says.  Install it, and you get an additional button on your plugin toolbar that looks like a plug.  With your pipe polyline layer in editing mode, select the features that you want to reverse the direction of, and click the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QGIS 1.8:

- go into the layer properties, and select the style tab.
- Click on the change button under the current depiction of the line
- In the new window select add symbol layer
- click on the drop down menu for symbol type and either select line decoration or marker line

Line decoration will place an arrow at the end of the line segment in the direction of travel.

Line marker you will need to click on the change button next to marker in the symbol layer properties. Select an arrow, and if needed change the default angle of the arrow.