# Show flow direction for pipes as arrows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, direction, flow

I have a vector layer (line features) which consists of different pipes. In the attribute data I have fields that indicate the upstream elevation and downstream elevation values.

I am trying to visually depict the flow direction in these pipes using arrows based on the upstream and downstream elevation values. I cannot seem to work out a method in QGIS. Is anyone here able to assist?

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67398/how-to-display-arrows-on-pipes-from-upstream-to-downstream-using-qgis

Comment: @PolyGeo I have a potential answer for the case when its too long to change the directions of all vectors, and I would like to post it. Could you please re-open the question? Or should I just answer the linked duplicate?

Comment: @Victor wouldn't that answer apply just as well to the duplicate?  That question is open for more answers.